# How to learn Matplotlib without searching Google or Stackoverflow?

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib, plot

I am not really new to Matplotlib.  I have made quite some figures with it, though I don't use it everyday (or every week, or even every month).  So I tend to forget some basic things, for example, how to add a legend, how to add a color bar, how to customize a colormap, how to change the font of a specific part of the figure, how to make some transparency effect, etc.  Of course, each time when I have a question, I can always google it and Google will most likely take me to stackoverflow or some other similar sites, or some blog articles, and I can almost always get a solution.  This gives me an impression that the ``official'' documentation is not as useful as it should be.

But I must be wrong, namely, the official documentation must be very useful, otherwise how do those people who answer the questions know the solutions?  Maybe they are ``insiders'' (developers of Matplotlib)?

**So my question is**, in case you are not a developer (but you are welcome to answer this question if you are), and suppose you have answered many Matplotlib-related questions here, how do you learn those techniques by yourself without asking Google?  Where and how do you look for if the answer does not come to your mind immediately (not Google, because it is you who is answering that question, and before that maybe the answer does not exist in Google yet)?

Note that I am *not* complaining about the documentation.  I think I just haven't found an efficient way to make use of it.

Or maybe finding the solution to a specific request is inevitably not straightforward due to the intrinsic complexity of Matplotlib?  By intrinsic complexity, I mean in Matplotlib similar things can usually be done in many different ways, thus if one happens to choose one specific (and uncommon for whatever reasons) way in the beginning, and later comes across a problem, the solution to this problem may not have been listed explicitly in the manual, and maybe only those gurus who know how Matplotlib really works under the hood can come up with a solution.

> To teach one how to fish is more helpful than to give one a fish.

Note: the specific problem I meet today is to add a color bar to a figure.  The slightly ``special'' thing in my case is that the main image is a collection of polygons, with the color of each one of them set individually.  So the simple colorbar function does not seem to work, at least not in a way as presented in the first Google result of "matplotlib colorbar example".  In this specific case it is indeed solved by the second Google result, but this is only discovered after many trials with the first Google result (and after searching with other keywords), which is kind of frustrating...  By the way, I used

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, ...)
```

to set up the axis box (which is necessary because my polygons have to be added to a preexistent axis frame), so I have to use

```
ax.xaxis.label.set_fontsize(20)
```

to change the font size of the xaxis label, which is only found out after quite some Googling.    How can I know by myself that ax has a property *xaxis*, *xaxis* has a property *label*, and *label* has a function *set_fontsize*, and the meaning of them when their names are not as obvious as here?

Comment: Well, there is Bing (e.g.) if you prefer ..

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/ has a “quick search” box which you could use.

Comment: You could always read the code and figure things out. Which is how a lot of community documentation gets written

Comment: In documentation for Axes it mentions a `get_xaxis` method which returns an Axis instance.  In the documentation for Axis it mentions a `get_label` method which returns a Text instance.  In the documentation for Text it lists a `set_fontsize` method.  It's true it requires some drilling down, but it's all there.

Comment: The documentation is very good as an API documentation, in that if you have the object structure in your head and know roughly what function you want, it is very easy to look up what you need to know.  I learned most of what I know by a) answering SO questions (it's a good exercise) b) the example gallery c) reading the docs to do a) and d) reading the source when c) failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the python commandline I usually try to find my way through matplotlib itself using Python to read through it.

Assume your example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, ...)
```

**Question**:

> How can I know by myself that ax has a property xaxis, xaxis has a property label, and label has a function set_fontsize

**Answer**:

Lookup the `dir`:

```
for item in dir(ax):
    print item
#or in case i guess there should be a setter for sth. i search:
for item in dir(ax):
    if item.startswith("set_"):
        print item
#or if i search sth. about labels:
for item in dir(ax):
    if "label" in item:
        print item
```

**Question**:

> and the meaning of them when their names are not as obvious as here

**Answer**:

When I've found sth. promising I read the `docstring`:

```
print ax.xaxis.label.set_size.__doc__
```

The docstrings in matplotlib are usually very useful and suffice to explain the setter and getter methods.

In case this does not help, I look for what class to search in the documentation:

```
>>>type(ax.xaxis.label)
<class 'matplotlib.text.Text'>
```

What - in this example - would take me [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

Comment: I think your approach is the right way to go.  Thanks!  Maybe being patient and cool and to work like a detective is the key, because sometimes when one is in a hurry to find the solution out, one cannot look very carefully at the documentation or the information included in "dir".